# access index and value of a scala list inside a map function

Tags: scala

val arr = List(8, 15, 22, 1, 10, 6, 18, 18, 1)
arr.zipWithIndex.map(_._2) works and give me index of the elements in the list
.How to access the index and the element as part of the map function

Comment: Your map function already has the value and the index, but you are discarding the value. So it is not clear to me what is the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
val arr = List(8, 15, 22, 1, 10, 6, 18, 18, 1)
arr.zipWithIndex.map(zippedList => (zippedList._1, zippedList._2))
```

if you want to access the element it's ._1 and index ._2

you can also use this:

```
arr.zipWithIndex.map {
    case (x, y) => print(x, y)
  }
```

and so the operation on x and y what ever you want to do.

Comment: Thanks Raman. I was trying to destruct the inside the parameter list itsef.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically done using `zipWithIndex` and pattern matching:

```
arr.zipWithIndex.map{ case (value, index) => ??? }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial function to deconstruct a tuple

```scala
val arr = List(8, 15, 22, 1, 10, 6, 18, 18, 1)
arr.zipWithIndex.map { case (value, index) => println(value -> index) }
```